# why does the simulator keep calling bannerView: didFailToReceiveAdWithError

Tags: iad, adbannerview

I've built a few apps that correctly implemented iAds.  The apps are live in the app store and ads are being shown.  I now can NOT get any app (including the ones that once worked correctly) to display an iAd on the device or the simulator.  I'm wondering if there is a glitch in xcode or something odd is going on. Perhaps I'm just overlooking something obvious.  I've done the following:

1) linked Binary with iAd.framework

```
2) #import <iAd/iAd.h>

3) #import <iAd/AdBannerView.h>

4) @interface RSBViewController :UIViewController <AdBannerViewDelegate>
```

5) added a AdBannerView object by my view controller on the storyboard

6) connected my AdBannerView to

```
  @propery (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *aBanner;
```

7) in the viewDidLoad method I did set the delegate like this:

```
  _aBanner.delegate = self
```

8) I've implemented -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(AdBannerView *) banner like this:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
NSLog(@"Loading iAd");
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL]; banner.frame =    CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; self.bannerIsVisible = YES; }
}
```

9) I've implemented - (void) bannerView:(AdBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error like this:

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed Loading iAd");
if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL]; banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; self.bannerIsVisible = NO; }
}
```

When I run this on the simulator or my device the output is:

```
2013-08-29 21:29:27.643 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:29:57.773 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:30:58.152 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:32:58.542 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:36:58.919 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:40:59.473 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
2013-08-29 21:45:00.997 iAdPracticeApp[1098:c07] Failed Loading iAd
```

I understand that Apple simulates loaded ads and failed to load ads.  I also realize that I can go into my developer setting of my iOS device and change the error rate to happen 0%, 50%, 80%, 100%.  No matter what I try I can't get an iAd to properly load.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realized that a lot of people are having this problem.  I read in the forum within iTunes Connect and just recently (within this last week) people have been mentioning the same issue.  Perhaps it's something with Apple's server or something.  Has anyone else had this issue?  Anyone have insight, advice, suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: i also have a live app which continues to show iAds, but when i run from xcode to simulator or device I haven't been able to see any ads over the last couple days. i thought it might be me, but i'm comforted to see a couple other people experiencing the issue. hopefully apple fixes soon